# how to reduce days of periods in unix time in java

Tags: java

I am facing some challenges in validate past week data, So that i want to create a data in any of the date in each last 8 weeks.
I am using below scripts

```
long currentTimeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();  
long last_week = System.currentTimeMillis() - n * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

Its working upto past 3 weeks while changing 'n' value as '7', '14', '21'. I can't go backward after that. Someone pls give suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the Calendar for date calculations

Comment: @Jens Calendar is a terrible API. Use JSR-310 added into Java 8 and available for Java 6+

Comment: @PeterLawrey just call it Date/time api... like localDate

Comment: @PeterLawrey Maybe but it is the only Thing you have in Standard Java in Versions lower than 8.

Comment: do it like that  `now = Calendar.getInstance();` 
    `now.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -n);` `n` is number of weeks to subsctract :) and then `int last_week = now.getTimeInMillis();`

Comment: @Jens it is still really awful and you can use it in Java 6 if you want.  I would rather use `long` (and in fact do)

Comment: thanks everyone who replied for my concerns. And @PeterLawrey it's working cool. Thanks again